# How to integrate drivers from Windows 10 disc image to Windows 7 disc image

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, drivers

I watched [this video](https://youtu.be/M-_FpYVgynI?t=71), which shows that it's possible to run Windows Vista in modern PCs. The author used NTLite to integrate drivers from Windows 7 to Vista's `/sources/boot.wim`. I installed NTLite but am unsure on how to integrate the drivers. I've got this after adding Windows 10 disc image to the integration queue:

[image: NTLite]

The <kbd>Export HW list</kbd> option generates a XML, so I'm lost here. How to export drivers from Windows 10 disc image to another Windows 7 disc image?

Comment: I've found this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rm1SiTF31IE I'm gonna try it and return here later.

Answer (score 2):

Windows Vista is dead.

Windows 7 may not run (90%+) on a modern machine and Vista stands next to no chance of running on a modern machine.

Instead of trying to run on a modern machine, set it up as a Virtual Machine. That will work. I have a Vista Business 64-bit virtual machine running.